# compiling scala program on jvm

Tags: scala

What version of the scala library jar will support java 1.5 and 1.6

And also how to compile in java?

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Answer (score 2):

Scala's jar files are compiled with JVM 1.5, as can be seen by looking into the `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file. Here is 2.8.1: `Created-By: 1.5.0_22-b03 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)`.

The Scala compiler generates output that is compatible with jvm-5 (see `scalac -target`). Also, it has some magic to enable use with jdk 1.6, in which `String` has added a method that Scala defines on `WrappedString`.

Comment: RichString is now StringOps/WrappedString/StringLike in 2.8.1 or? (Someone corrected me on that last week)

Comment: @oluies It is. What can I say? I'm an old hand in Scala. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Scala is compiled with the scalac compiler and not javac. To run the Scala code you need Java runtime/sdk version 1.5 or later and the scala library jar.

Version 2.7.7 and 2.8.1 are the common versions used today. If you start a new project now you should aim for 2.8.1 or 2.9 (which is going to be available soon-ish). Download site is [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/downloads)

See the [FAQ](http://www.scala-lang.org/faq/1)